despite the disconnection I still have access to the resources without authenticating to my provider again
my application logout doesn't work.
When I click on the button logout, I stay connected the same if the log out is confirmed-> I don't need to log in again for access to resources, I have direct access to the resources page.
The log-out confirmation windows don't appear, and if I write /logout:

but I have always access to resources without log in, again.
in the browser console, I have this:

Security config for Customers:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)

public class SecurityConfig  {
   
    private final ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;
   
    public  SecurityConfig(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository){
        this.clientRegistrationRepository=clientRegistrationRepository;
    }

    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(Customizer.withDefaults())//config par def.
                .authorizeHttpRequests(ar-> ar.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .headers(h->h.frameOptions(fo->fo.disable()))
                .csrf(crsf->crsf.ignoringRequestMatchers("/h2-console/**"))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(ar->ar.requestMatchers("/","/webjars/**","/h2-console/**",  "/oauth2Login/**").permitAll())
                .oauth2Login(al->al.loginPage("/oauth2Login").defaultSuccessUrl("/"))
                .logout((logout)->logout
                        .logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler())
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
                        .clearAuthentication(true)
                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID"))
                        .exceptionHandling(eh->eh.accessDeniedPage("/notAuthorized"));
        return http.build();

    }

    private OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler oidcLogoutSuccessHandler() {
        final OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler oidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler=
                new OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler(this.clientRegistrationRepository);
        oidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri("{baseUrl}?logoutsuccess=true");
        return oidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler;
    }
    @Bean
    public GrantedAuthoritiesMapper userAuthoritiesMapper() {
        return (authorities -> {
            final Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities=new HashSet<>();
            authorities.forEach((authority)->{
                if (authority instanceof OidcUserAuthority oidcAuth){
                    mappedAuthorities.addAll(mappedAuthorities(oidcAuth.getIdToken().getClaims()));
                    System.out.println(oidcAuth.getAttributes());
                } else if (authority instanceof OAuth2UserAuthority oauth2Auth) {
                    mappedAuthorities.addAll(mappedAuthorities(oauth2Auth.getAttributes()));
                }
            });
        return mappedAuthorities;

    });
    }

    private List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities(final Map<String, Object> attributes) {
        final Map<String, Object> realmAccess= (Map<String, Object>) attributes.getOrDefault("realm_access", Collections.emptyMap());
        final Collection<String> roles=((Collection<String>)realmAccess.getOrDefault("roles", Collections.emptyList()));
        return roles.stream()
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .toList();
    }

controller:
@Controller   
    public class CustomerController {
        /**
         * acces a interface
         */
        private  CustomerRepository customerRepository;
        private ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;
        public CustomerController(CustomerRepository customerRepository, ClientRegistrationRepository registrationRepository) {
            this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
            this.clientRegistrationRepository = clientRegistrationRepository;
        }


        @GetMapping("/customers")
        @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
        public String customers(Model model){  
            List<Customer> customersList = customerRepository.findAll();
            model.addAttribute("customers", customersList);
            return "customers";//return attributeName du model=CustomerList
        }

        @GetMapping("/products")
        
        public String products(Model model){
            SecurityContext context= SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
            Authentication authentication = context.getAuthentication();
            OAuth2AuthenticationToken oAuth2AuthenticationToken = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication;
            DefaultOidcUser oidcUser= (DefaultOidcUser) oAuth2AuthenticationToken.getPrincipal();
            String jwtTokenValue=oidcUser.getIdToken().getTokenValue();
            RestClient restClient= RestClient.create("http://localhost:8085");
            List<Product> products=restClient.get()
                    .uri("/products")
                    .headers(httpHeaders ->httpHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,"Bearer"+"jwtTokenValue"))
                    .retrieve()
                    .body(new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {});
            model.addAttribute("products", products);
            return "products";
        }


        
        @GetMapping("/auth")
        @ResponseBody
        public Authentication auth(Authentication authentication){
            return authentication;
        }
      
        @GetMapping("/")
        public String index(){
            return "index";
        }

        @GetMapping("/notAuthorized")
        public String notAuthorized(){
            return "notAuthorized";
        }

        @GetMapping("/oauth2Login")
        public String oauth2Login(Model model){
            String authorizationRequestBaseUri="oauth2/authorization";
            Map<String, String> oauth2AuthenticationUrls=new HashMap();
            Iterable<ClientRegistration> clientRegistrations=(Iterable<ClientRegistration>)clientRegistrationRepository;
            clientRegistrations.forEach(clientRegistration->{
                oauth2AuthenticationUrls.put(clientRegistration.getClientName(),
                        authorizationRequestBaseUri+"/"+ clientRegistration.getRegistrationId());
            });
            model.addAttribute("urls",oauth2AuthenticationUrls);
            return "oauth2Login";
        }

thanks for your help.

How is the front end coded?  Nest.js, for example, loves to cache things like your JWT and, unless told otherwise, blindly keeps it well past it's expiration.  You may need both server and client side logout code.

@stdunbar he is using oauth2Login => requests are authorized with a session cookie (not a token) and he logout should invalidate this session.

The request to /logout should be a POST (which means that CSRF protection is going to come in the game) and, as you configured an OIDC logout success handler, the redirection should be to the authorization server. Here you are redirected to login because logout is rejected (wrong HTTP verb).
Once you have fixed the HTTP verb (send a POST request instead of a GET), you'll probably face CSRF issues because you are using a SPA and did not configure CSRF protection for such applications...

it was already a post request

Logout

And what about the CSRF part of the answer?

I don't see the log with CSRF but I read that: Stateless Spring API
Let’s review the case of a stateless Spring API consumed by a front end.
As explained in our dedicated article, we need to understand if CSRF protection is required for our stateless API.
If our stateless API uses token-based authentication, such as JWT, we don’t need CSRF protection, and we must disable it as we saw earlier.
However, if our stateless API uses a session cookie authentication, we need to enable CSRF protection as we’ll see next.

csrf is configurated by default in my code:public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http.csrf(Customizer.withDefaults())
.[....]
.csrf(crsf->crsf.ignoringRequestMatchers("/h2-console/**"))

my project uses JsessionId and a keycloak token, what choice should I make?
I don't see the log with CSRF
